# Transparency in Labels/annotations using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, annotation, transparency-opacity

I am trying to get my labels transparent. I have converted them into annotation and unable to make the annotations transparent. I have kept annotation in the map. My annotation layer does not appear on table of contents!

How can I get the labels transparent or annotations transparent?

Answer (score 6):

You said that you are keep your adnotation in the map but if you save them in a database

[image]

You will have full control over the adnotation, including transparency

[image]

This may be what you have been looking for:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You will find the annotation layer in the properties of your dataframe. I do not know how to make them transparent.